# Visual Studio C# e.Location error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

i have a error in Visual Studio C#.
it says that event args doesnt know a solution for e.location

i used dutch words in this exercise here are the translations for them:

Voer de lengte in: - input the length

voer een breedte in: - input a width

kies een kleur: kleur - input color: color

kies een lijndikte: - choose a line thickness

klik mij: - click me

rechthoek -  rectangle

omtrek - circumference

oppervlakte - surface

middelpunt - center

here is a picture of how the application looks like:
[image: the form for my application]
here is my code:

my code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rechthoek
{
    public partial class Form_Main : Form
    {
        int lengte = 0;
        int breedte = 0;
        Color Kleur = Color.Blue;
        int LijnDikte = 1;
        Point middelpunt = new Point(0, 0);

        public Form_Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //
        }

        private void btn_uitkomst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rechthoek rechthoek = new rechthoek(lengte, breedte, this, middelpunt, LijnDikte, Kleur);
            lbl_Omtrek.Text = lbl_Omtrek.Text + rechthoek.omtrek().ToString();
            lbl_oppervlakte.Text = lbl_oppervlakte.Text + rechthoek.oppervlakte().ToString();
            rechthoek.teken();
        }

        private void txt_lengte_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lengte = int.Parse(txt_lengte.Text);
        }

        private void txt_Breedte_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            breedte = int.Parse(txt_Breedte.Text);
        }

        private void btn_Kleur_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
            Kleur = colorDialog1.Color;
        }

        private void txt_LijnDikte_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LijnDikte = int.Parse(txt_LijnDikte.Text);
        }

        private void Form_Main_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            middelpunt = e.Location;
        }
    }
}
```

class rectangle:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rechthoek
{
    class rechthoek
    {
        private Point _Middelpunt = new Point(0, 0);
        private int _lengte = 0;
        private int _breedte = 0;
        private Form _Form = new Form();
        private Color _Kleur = Color.Red;
        private int _breedte2 = 1;
        private int lengte;
        private int breedte;
        private Form_Main form_Main;
        private Point middelpunt;
        private int lijnDikte;
        private Color kleur;

        public rechthoek(int lengte, int breedte, Form form, Color kleur, int LijnDikte)
        {
            _lengte = lengte;
            _breedte = breedte;
            _Form = form;
            _Kleur = kleur;
            _breedte2 = LijnDikte;

        }

        public rechthoek(int lengte, int breedte, Form_Main form_Main, Point middelpunt, int lijnDikte, Color kleur)
        {
            this.lengte = lengte;
            this.breedte = breedte;
            this.form_Main = form_Main;
            this.middelpunt = middelpunt;
            this.lijnDikte = lijnDikte;
            this.kleur = kleur;
        }

        public double oppervlakte()
        {
            return _lengte * _breedte;
        }

        public double omtrek()
        {
            return 2 * (_lengte + _breedte);
        }

        public void teken()
        {
            Pen mijnPen = new Pen(_Kleur, _breedte2);
            Graphics papier = _Form.CreateGraphics();
            papier.DrawRectangle(mijnPen, _Middelpunt.X, _Middelpunt.Y, _lengte * 2, _breedte * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

so in the first code sample on the near end you can see e.Location and the eroor message is "EventArgs doesnt contain a definition for Location..."

EDIT: the error for e.Location is gone now now i only need to change this line 
this.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Form_Main_Click);

i hope you can help me!
kind regards;
Zaftan

Comment: I take it you want the mouse location?

Comment: yes the exercise says i should indeed have it with a mouse click on the form

Comment: `e` is declared as an event argument,it doesn't have any method/property called Location,what is ur motive ??

Comment: Change `Form_Main_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` to `Form_Main_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)`, then `e.Location` will be available.

Comment: thank you ron it was indeed what you commented!
i do get this error now though:
this.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Form_Main_Click);

Comment: @Zaftan,take a look at my solution , it may help you in future :)

Comment: thank you zack ill remember it for the future!

Comment: You want the MouseClick event instead of the Click event.  Those int.Parse() calls are going to get you into trouble, use TryParse and don't try when there is no text because the user back-spaced the entry.

Comment: out of all those anwsers that was the one i was lookign for i would like to thank everyone for helping and fixing the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using the `Click` Event of the form which does not provide mouse coordinates.

Instead, use the `MouseClick` event.

```
private void Form_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Note that it is not enough to just change the name of the method and type of the parameter e. In the properties window in Visual Studio, you also need to assign the method to the `MouseClick` event.

[image]

Comment: You are right, I keep confusing `Click` with `MouseClick`, poor naming on the designer's part I think.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the location of the Cursor,in your case,just modify the line as follows :

```
 private void Form_Main_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
middelpunt = e.Location;
}
```

In other cases,if you want to get cursor position :

```
Point coordinates = Cursor.Position;
```